# Fragments not fitting correctly in Tab Layout / ViewPager2

Tags: android, android-tablayout, android-viewpager2

I've tried a few different ways at getting this to work but the fragments I host inside of the ViewPager for a tab layout don't display correctly unless I position the components in the fragments oddly. Here's my fragment_tab xml and code is in Java:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="37dp" />

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" />

</LinearLayout>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnPost"
    android:layout_width="147dp"
    android:layout_height="47dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:text="Post"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And for instance in one of the fragments I host inside of it, the XML is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">


<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
    android:layout_width="387dp"
    android:layout_height="491dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="387dp"
        android:layout_height="491dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>


<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:layout_height="103dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_marginBottom="342dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtViewEmpty"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and this is what the design view looks like below. This fragment is hosted inside of the view pager with the tabs, inside of another screen that has an action bar but the tabs is hosted within that one.

[image: Design view]

I've been testing on Android Studio using an emulator and then when I test on hardware the UI is all messed up, but also positioning the screens like above, ideally I'd like to be able to use the whole view for the recycler view without having to place it like that as it may look right on my emulator but not hardware device if I use match_parent or the whole screen. Any ideas? I tried coordinator layout and relative layout as well and couldn't get it exact, it's possible it was done incorrectly though.

Thanks all!!

**Edit:** Picture on the hardware device where its messed up, but looks fine on emulator in the odd position that view was created with:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I'm not really sure what is wrong because you did not provided an example of how this looks on your phone. But, I can see in the constraint layout that you did not set the LinearLayout to start at the start of the parent, that might cause the issue. Be very careful with the constraints.

Comment: I updated the question with a screenshot from the hardware device. I did try the start at start of parent but still had some issues when trying to get that view thats put inside the view pagers to use its full screen instead of the odd position.

Comment: You can add a startToStart of parent to the LinearLayout that holds the viewpager (just for safety). And the on the XML with recyclerView - i strongly suggest you to make the content a bit more dinamic. Set the width and height to wrap_content or match_parent and add margins to the sides you want. Same goes with swiperefreshlayout. These raw values might cause some issues.